# Why does my post get deleted or rejected by Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I am trying to ask a question about an email file that I have produced that makes a blank record when it's read. I am not sure why everytime I post this it's getting deleted. Can anyone help?

Comment: What happens when you attempt to ask the question?

Comment: Now i am getting -ve votes and i do not understand this system

Comment: Because you asked that question [here on Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173475/email-format-produces-a-blank-email-i-am-wondering-if-anyone-can-help-me-and-let). And it's off-topic here. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: It gets deleted and I am not given a reason just that its not a question even though i give the file of the mail redacted with the Emelia names. Thankyou Bart but am unsure why that is so. As its a programming issue of format that I cant solve.

Comment: Read the last link I've given you. Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow are entirely different sites. Don't mix the two.

Comment: Thanks Bart I choose post from my account so have no idea which it posted too. What is the difference please?

Comment: @MartinTheeDrummer - there's two nifty links at the top of the page:  [About](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) and [FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) that might be of interest

Comment: @MartinTheeDrummer Each site has a FAQ linked at the top. Read those for both sites (http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) The difference should be pretty clear. Read them.

Comment: Hi Martin, I seriously recommend you work on your question asking skills first, and try to work through the resources provided to you in the comments to your Stack Overflow questions (including the "learn more" link that probably pops up when you try to post a question on the main site.) There is an automatic block for content regarded as unsuitable for the site and you seem to have triggered it.

Comment: I saw the learn more link and followed their comments but this didn't help. I dont think i understand why it got triggered I have only posted three posts.

Comment: With those 3 posts you have a total score of -14, and one of them was closed. If others have been deleted on SO as well, that would make the situation even worse. All in all you've been banned because your contributions were not good enough.

Comment: On closer look, I agree the voting on your questions has been a bit harsh, but two of them are simply not of the standard that Stack Overflow expects and need improving. The "HTML box" one is extremely ambigous and unanswerable, you need to clarify what you're asking. Even though it lacks basic debugging, I'll cast a sympathy upvote on the E-Mail question (and answer it) as it seems to have been misunderstood by most users who voted on it. Still, do work through the resources provided. If you have problems with the guidance, point out what part you are having problems with *specifically*.

Comment: Pekka the post has been closed again . I am not getting any further help . I do not understand your system at all it seems you are all far to busy answering questions from emails from new users like me about their closed posts. to really help :-( I really do not understand your system and what it has been set up for as it does not aid new users to have questions solved in my experiance. I have spent more time typing on this forum than  I have solving my problem!

Answer (score 3):

You're posting your email question to *meta* (same site we're on right now). You should post on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) instead.

If you can't post questions to Stack Overflow anymore, this question should help you out: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

Comment: It appears he is question banned on SO; is this the case?

Comment: Note though that the OP already seems to have done so (in addition to posting on Meta): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602565/blank-email-no-error-when-sending-email-with-php

Comment: Yeah, he's probably banned, and for good reason.

Comment: Thanks Bart Not for a good reason if I dont know why. I went to my account and chose post why is this not correct and what should i be doing please?

Comment: Bart I asked a question if anyone had a working message box code that all my third post. I then got a message saying i was banned and am none the wiser as all my posts disappeared.

Comment: @MartinTheeDrummer To be blunt, you are banned because you have asked multiple questions of extremely poor quality.

Comment: @MartinTheeDrummer More than I could ever tell you about bans, their cause, and what to do about them is explained here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers Please read all of it.

Comment: Yes I read this Bart . I was removing email addresses and redacting personal information form my upload I had not spotted. I was not aware deleting posts or editing them was wrong either if what you had put the first time was not clear.

Comment: Mystical how can providing my source code and output and asking what i need to change be get it working be a bad question. I got told to use the debugger when I was not asking about my source code. I was asking why the output would not work in an email package. I am capable of editing code . But if i dont know what its supposed to produce or producing format wise which is rejected by outlook. I dont think this is a poor quality question can you explain

Comment: What's the point of showing the PHP code if it executes fine, but generates an invalid email? Can't you just show the (raw) invalid email so it's clear what your problem is? Also, pretty sure the headers following each mime boundary need to be terminated by \r\n\r\n, with no space in between.

Comment: Again my post has been closed stating  something about not suitable for geographic area and is not relevant ? when people started posting answers what is the point of this service on the internet exactly as all it seems is that you have to talk why your posts gets pulled other than getting an answer to your question you asked

Comment: The \r\n\r\n has not made the email show in outlook either. Thank  you for your help

Comment: Now my account is closed again from Posting to Stack overflow I have to say what a waste of space this website is and waste of time. The rubbish i see on her code wise never works and it would be better if this code was not  drowning google searches. Please close your site it is not worthy of a server .